# Why does adding a destructor change the copy constructor behavior of this struct?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a bit of code that I find confusing. In particular, when I try to add something to a list as an initializer-list - it works until I add a destructor - then it starts trying to find a copy constructor.

This doesn't seem to be completely consistent behavior. Take this minimal example:

```
#include <list>
int main()
{
    class MemberType
    {
    public:
        MemberType()  {}
        MemberType(MemberType&& copy) { }
    };
    struct ListItemType
    {
        MemberType x;
        ~ListItemType() {}
    };
    std::list<ListItemType> myList;
    myList.push_back({MemberType()});
    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile in [GCC](http://ideone.com/3jguK0) and VS2015 because the `push_back` attempts to access the `ListItemType` copy constructor:

```
main()::ListItemType::ListItemType(const main()::ListItemType&)
```

(as per my understanding). This seems to make some sense as the list `push_back` will make a copy (since there is no move constructor), except this is **not** the behavior if you remove the destructor. Comment out the destructor and the compilation succeeds as expected.

That said, the following works fine even with the destructor - no copy or move constructors are needed to satisfy it. This seems like the same behavior to me though.

```
ListItemType foo = { MemberType() };
```

Finally, if you delete or comment out the move constructor of `MemberType` - the compilation again succeeds - meaning the following will compile.

```
#include <list>
int main()
{
    class MemberType
    {
    public:
        MemberType()  {}
    };
    struct ListItemType
    {
        MemberType x;
        ~ListItemType() {}
    };
    std::list<ListItemType> myList;
    myList.push_back({MemberType()});
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain the behavior here? Why does the `push_back` try to access the copy constructor of `ListItemType` - but only if `ListItemType` has a destructor and `MemberType` has a move constructor?

Comment: In short: adding a destructor suppresses generation of implicit move constructor , so the copy/move operation falls back to implicit copy-constructor

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The behaviour you are observing is generated by the rules that govern whether implicit copy or move constructors are generated by the compiler:

#### Implicit Move

If not defined, a move constructor is implicitly **declared** for a class if:

- the class has no user defined copy constructors; and
- the class has no user defined copy assignment or move assignment operators; and
- the class has no user defined destructor.

#### Implicit Copy

If not defined, a copy constructor is implicitly **deleted** for a class if:

- the class has a user defined move constructor; or
- other reasons which are not relevant here ...

---

In your question you have several cases:

#### Case 1

- `ListItemType` has a destructor
- `MemberType` has a move constructor

The implicit move constructor for `ListItemType` has been deleted due to the existence of the destructor.  Thus `push_back` must use a copy constructor to place the `ListItemType` into the list.

In that case, a copy constructor for `ListItemType` cannot be implicitly declared as one of its data members (`MemberType`) contains a move constructor, which prevents an implicit copy constructor for `MemberType` being generated.

#### Case 2

- `ListItemType` has no destructor
- `MemberType` has a move constructor

A move constructor can be implicitly generated for `ListItemType` and used to move the value into the list.

#### Case 3

- `ListItemType` has a destructor
- `MemberType` has no move constructor

An implicit copy constructor for `ListItemType` and `MemberType` can be generated and used to copy the value into the list.

Finally, the expression `ListItemType foo = { MemberType() };` is aggregate initialization and follows different rules.  In either case `MemberType` will have either a move or copy constructor that is sufficient for aggregate initialization.

Comment: Thanks very much for the excellent and detailed answer. I was able to overcome the problem based on this revelation by explicitly requesting the default move constructor (ListItemType(ListItemType&&) = default;).  One day, when I'm very old, I hope to finally understand the details of C++ :)

Comment: @Ben http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)